# MEF and EF Intercepters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mef, interceptor

I have what seemed to be a straightforward MEF Export.

```
[Export(typeof(IDbCommandInterceptor))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class LoggingCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    [Import]
    private ILogging _ILogger;        

    public void NonQueryExecuting(
   DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        Log(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    private void Log<TResult>(
    DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (!interceptionContext.IsAsync)
        {
            _ILogger.LogWarn("Non-async command used: {0}", command.CommandText);
        }
        else
            _ILogger.LogTrace("command used: {0}", command.CommandText);
    }
    ect.....
```

Then the Wire up

```
public class EFConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{

    public EFConfiguration()
    {
        AddInterceptor(new LoggingCommandInterceptor());
    }

}
```

So the issue is the Import [Ilogging] in LoggingCommandInterceptor is always NULL its never filled,  when I check my composition containter I see the Export registered correctly so I'm at a lost why my Import is not satisfied.

Comment: If you manually instantiate the LoggingCommandInterceptor class then MEF never has a chance to satisfy any imports... you should allow MEF to instantiate any classes you want satisfied.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul going down that road I change my EFConfiguration to this  [Import]
        IDbCommandInterceptor _mefInterceptor;

        public EFConfiguration()
        {
            AddInterceptor(_mefInterceptor);
        }  Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

attacking this a different way, I used the following after the MEF Container is setup

```
[Import]
    private IDbCommandInterceptor _LoggingCommandInterceptor;
public MefConfig()
    {          
     // MEF SETUP ... ///
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(_LoggingCommandInterceptor);

    }
```

Which works as expected.